# Chrome extension: content script not finding dom elements

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension and have the following code

popup.html:

```
   <script type='text/javascript' src='content.js'></script>
```

content.js:

```
var container = document.getElementById('viewer')
container.style['white-space'] = 'nowrap'

var node_list = document.getElementsByClassName('page')
Array.prototype.forEach.call(node_list, function(page) {
  page.style['display'] = 'inline-block'
})
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "horizontal_pdf",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "My Title",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/16x16.jpg",
            "32": "icons/32x32.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

But when I click on the icon, and look at the console, I see the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

at line 2 of content.js. So, it's not able to find the div with id `viewer`. But when I look at the page's dom, it's there. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I don't have content scripts specified in the manifest since I don't want it to get triggered automatically, but only when the user clicks on the icon.

Comment: Is the script perhaps running before that part of the DOM is ready?

Comment: What does your manifest look like?

Comment: updated with manifest

Comment: so your code in content.js is looking for an element in the popup?

Comment: Nope, the actual page

Comment: I guess my question is how do I access the page's Dom from content.js without specifying it in the manifest or specify it without triggering it on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google's documentation you can use programmatic injection.

In a background script you can add:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"});
});
```

Or maybe in you popup script you can call:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"});
```

(You'll need to add the `activeTab` permission any way)

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi

Answer (score -1):

if you want get dom in popup.html / js you have to add content.js for a content script, and then send a message to popup.js ou can call content.js from popup.js to get informations... background script can no access to the dom... it is what i've done...